# React Hooks: Adding new fields to an Object state does not get reflected immediately

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am using React Hooks to manage states within a component.

```
const addNode = () => {
    let pform = pForm
    let handles = [vForm, yForm, hForm]
    let access_info = [virtualForm, management1Form, management2Form, consoleForm]
    let newObj = {
        ...currentForm,
        p: pform,
        handles: handles,
        access_info: access_info,
    }
    console.log('newObj', newObj)
    setCurrentForm(
        newRouterObj
    )
    console.log(currentForm)
    let currArr = [...addedNodes]
    currArr.push(currentForm)
    setAddedNodes(currArr)
    intializeForms()
}
```

The function above is an `onClick` that I use when I press an `Add` button. The forms (`pForm, vForm, yForm, etc.`) are all separate states. I gather them together and put them into a single object `newObj` and use `setCurrentForm` to update the `currentForm` state to `newObj`.

When I `console.log` the `newObj`, everything goes in fine. However, when I check the `currentForm` after the `setCurrentForm`, the fields (`p`, `handles`, and `access_info`) are empty.

I know that states in React can have a delay in updates so I might have to use `useEffect`. However, in my use case, which is to gather different states and put them in as a new field in the `currentForm` state seems `useEffect` is not the best way to solve it. Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are misunderstanding exactly how `useState` works. When you call the `useState` setter function, the state value isn't actually updated immediately, instead it will trigger the component to re-render with the updated value. Even though you call the setter half way through the function, the state value will remain the original value for the entire lifetime of that function call.

You could slightly tweak what you have to be

```
const addNode = () => {
    ...
    let currArr = [...addedNodes]
    // you know that currentForm is supposed to be newObj, so just push that
    // see my explanation above to understand why it currentForm isn't what you expect
    currArr.push(newObj)
    ...
}
```

Comment: Wow. Didn't know the fix would be this simple. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's an async action so values will not be assigned/updated instantly. You need to watch for the changes using `useEffect` hook to log new values and to do anything in case

```js
useEffect(() => {
 // Whenever `currentForm` will be updated, this callback will be invoked
 
 console.log('updated currentForm values', currentForm);
},[currentForm]);
```